# How to add the default value to the smarty date dropdown?

Tags: smarty

I am creating a `date dropdown using smarty syntax` which will display **only the years**.

It is showing perfectly with current year being selected.

But I **want to show a text** e.g. `"Select Year" with value=' '` and on clicking it will show me the rest of years in the dropdown to select.

Could anyone suggest how to do it in smarty ?

Below is my code..

```
{html_select_date prefix="from" display_days=false display_months=false start_year=-20 month_extra='id="fromMonth"' year_extra='id="fromYear"'}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Smarty 3, just add two parameters more to the function:

```
year_empty="Select year" time=null
```

Comment: But It is not getting selected by default. Current year is getting selected ?

Comment: How can I select "Select year" for default value, @Borgtex ?